# How to know if a period overlaps another

Tags: python, django

I'd like to make an application that allows me to reserve an item during a specified period.

I need a function to check if the specified item is already booked during the period i want to use it (so the booking should fail). Can you help me?

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import *
from django.db.models import Q
import datetime
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
class Reservation(models.Model):
        date_debut = models.DateTimeField('debut de la reservation')
        date_fin = models.DateTimeField('fin de la reservation')
        obj_res = models.ForeignKey('Materiel')
        notice = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        personne = models.ForeignKey('Personne')
        def __int__(self):
                return self.id

        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            new_start_date = datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 16, 10, 00)
            new_end_date = datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 16, 11, 00)
            material = Materiel.objects.get(nom="Bimaire 1")

            clashing_reservations = Reservation.objects.filter(obj_res=material).filter(
                Q(date_debut__lte=new_start_date, date_fin__gte=new_start_date) |
                Q(date_debut__lt=new_end_date, date_fin__gte=new_end_date)
            )
            if clashing_reservations.exists():
                raise ValidationError('Those dates clash with another reservation.')    

            return super(Reservation, self).save(*args, **kwargs)   


class Materiel(models.Model):
        nom = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        responsable = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        modalites = models.CharField(max_length=200)

        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.nom


class Personne(models.Model):
        nom = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        prenom = models.CharField(max_length=200)

        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.nom
```

views.py

```
def reservation(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = ReservationForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
                form.save()



    else:
        form = ReservationForm()

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))

    args["form"] = form

    return render_to_response("reservation.html", args)
```

EDIT
Thanks so far it's seems to work.
But now i want define that new_start_date and new_end_date are the actual values of the form.

Comment: You have to compare the start and end times of each reservation.

Comment: Period overlaps another if first periods start date or end date is between other periods start and end date or vice versa

Answer (score 4):

This is untested code, but I believe that this logic should test whether any other reservations overlap the one submitted in the form. This should probably be put in a `clean` method of the form, or some other validation. Perhaps even on the `save` method of the `Reservation` model:

```
from django.db.models import Q

new_start_date = datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 16, 10, 00)
new_end_date = datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 16, 11, 00)
material = Materiel.objects.get(nom='Whatever')

clashing_reservations = Reservation.objects.filter(objet=material).filter(
    Q(date_debut__lte=new_start_date, date_fin__gte=new_start_date) |
    Q(date_debut__lt=new_end_date, date_fin_gte=new_end_date)
)
if clashing_reservations.exists():
    raise ValidationError('Those dates clash with another reservation.')
```

Comment: Works for all overlapping cases (including datetimes), except the one where the block to be created overlaps the existing block entirely. (creating a block for 4-7, and a 3-6 block is present).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the format your dates are in but regardless you can use the module **datetime** to compare (subtract, add, higher/lower etc.) dates and times with one another.

So I've made a simple example to illustrate its use (I presume your format is months/days/years):

```
from datetime import *
debut_date = datetime.strptime(date_debut_db, "%m/%d/%y")
fin_date = datetime.strptime(date_fin_db, "%m/%d/%y")

debut_date2 = datetime.strptime(date_debut_form, "%m/%d/%y")
fin_date2 = datetime.strptime(date_fin_form, "%m/%d/%y")

if (debut_date2 > debut_date and debut_date2 < fin_date) or (fin_date2 > debut_date and fin_date2 < fin_date): 
    print "Impossible!"
else:
    print "Possible!"
```

**date_debut_db** and **date_fin_db** are the dates you get out of your database whereas **date_debut_form** and **date_fin_form** are the ones that the user fills in.